# System.TypeLoadException with MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, f#, mono, monodevelop, linux-mint

Yesterday I installed MonoDevelop 3.0 on my Linux Mint 13 setup by following the steps suggested in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181142/how-do-i-install-monodevelop-2-10-or-later-on-12-04). However when I try to create a new solution, of any of the provided types, I get the following error:

```
An error has occurred.

A type load exception has occurred.

System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

What does this error mean, and how do I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: That looks like some internal P/Invoke call (i.e., a managed call into native code) failed within the Mono engine itself -- perhaps there's some compatibility issue with Linux Mint.

Comment: @JackP., thanks. Possible solutions?

Comment: Are you getting this error for any project type (e.g., C#, F#, etc.) or only F# projects?

Comment: @knocte, Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-5~dhx1~precise1)

Answer (score 3):

One of my development machines is set up to dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04, and since I only had Monodevelop 2.8 installed on Ubuntu, I thought I'd follow the steps from the answer you referenced (from askubuntu).

When I ran the `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:directhex/ppa` command, I got a big warning message that said that PPA always contained the latest, *possibly unstable* sources for Monodevelop, and recommended using the PPA from [badgerports.org](http://badgerports.org) instead. Badgerports only uses stable, tested sources -- as of this writing, it has Monodevelop version `3.0.3.2+dfsg-1~dhx1~precise1`.

So, I hit `Ctrl+C` to cancel out of the `apt-add-repository` command, and instead followed these [instructions to set up the Badgerports PPA](http://badgerports.org/help.html). After that, I ran the commands to update the local package databases and install Monodevelop:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install monodevelop
```

Once monodevelop was installed, I was able to launch it and create/build/debug a new C# sample project without issues.

To install the F# add-in, I found an 'Add-ins' option under one of the top-level menus ('Tools', I think), expanded the 'Language Bindings' node of the tree, selected the F# Language Binding and clicked 'Install'. At that point, I was able to create/build/debug a new F# project without issues.

Caveat: I copied an existing F# project over from Windows/VS2010, then tried to build/debug it. I got an error similar to yours, then Monodevelop crashed badly (I had to `kill` the process).

If you can't get Monodevelop working after installing it from Badgerports, you should contact both the Mono and Monodevelop developers to have them investigate this -- that exception message leads me to believe it could be a bug within Mono, but there could also be a bug in Monodevelop which is triggering it.

Comment: Unable to set up badgerports PPA here. Software manager says the GPG key could be corrupted or invalid.